# Como construir um parse básico para tratar uma sentença e extrair uma ação contida nela que sera executada?

Tags: python, parser

Estou tentando montar um simples *parse* para analisar comandos inseridos por um usuário para um game de tipo [Text Adventure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_game). Entretanto, eu nunca tive experiencia com isso e não sei se a estrutura e os tipos de palavras que estou a usar estão corretas.

A classe `Parse` contem a estrutura básica das sentença que será analisada, veja:

```
class Parse(object):
    def __init__(self, sentenca=''):
        self.sentenca = sentenca
        self.acoes = ['pega', 'use', 'olhe', 'ir', 'examine']
        self.verbos = ['pegar', 'usar', 'olhar', 'examinar']
        self.direcoes = ['norte', 'sul', 'leste','oeste']
        self.acaoatual = None
        self.direcaodestino = None
        if not self.sentenca.strip():
            raise Exception('A setenca informada nao eh uma setenca valida.')            
    
    @staticmethod
    def _extrairpalavras(sentenca=''):        
        if not sentenca:
            return None
        return sentenca.lower().split(' ')

    def parseAcao(self):        
        palavras = Parse._extrairpalavras(sentenca=self.sentenca)
        if palavras:
            for p in palavras:
                if p in self.acoes or p in self.verbos:
                    self.acaoatual = p
                    break
    
    def parseDirecao(self):
        palavras = Parse._extrairpalavras(sentenca=self.sentenca)
        if palavras:
            for p in palavras:
                if p in self.direcoes:
                    self.direcaodestino = p
                    break
```

Um pequeno exemplo de uso:

```
parse = Parse('pegar item')
parse.parseAcao()
parse.parseDirecao()
print(parse.acaoatual)
print(parse.direcaodestino)
```

Saída:

> pegar
> None

A ideia aqui é futuramente usar este *parse* com outras duas classes que são:

Classe `Ambiente`:

```
class Ambiente(object):
    def __init__(self, id=None, titulo='', descricao='', itens=[]):
        self.id = id
        self.titulo = titulo
        self.descricao = descricao
        self.itens = itens
```

E `Item`:

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, id=None, descricao='', texto='', pegavel=False, pegado=False, usado=False):
        self.id = id
        self.descricao = descricao
        self.texto = texto
        self.pegavel = pegavel
        self.pegado = pegado
        self.usado = usado
```

No qual a classe `Ambiente` representa uma sala que o protagonista esteja, e sera possível navegar de uma sala para outra.

E a classe `Item` serão itens pegáveis, usáveis ou não que estarão em determinados ambientes, alguns são um complemento da história. Claro que criarei outras classes, até uma classe para representar o protagonista. E este parse que criei esta muito limitado e foi até a onde eu consegui chegar.

Posto isto, eu estou com dúvidas relacionadas a regras de gramática e a estrutura e a forma que o parse deve analisar a sentença que foi informada pelo usuário. Tendo em vista que as ações primordiais para o funcionamento básico do jogo que eu quero e que podem ser executadas são:

```
 - Olhar
 - Locomover
 - Pegar um Item
 - Usar um Item
 - Examinar um item
```

Assim eu já consigo ter um jogo básico e funcional limitando apenas estas ações acima. Abaixo segue as perguntas.

## Perguntas

1. De que forma eu poderia construir um *parse* básico para tratar uma sentença e fazer com que ele
   trate as palavras e correlacione elas com a **ação** que
   será executada?
2. Eu preciso adotar algumas regras gramaticais? Se sim quais?
3. É necessário usar uma estrutura de dados como uma *arvore* para o
   parse ou uma simples *lista* já basta?

Comment: As suas perguntas são muito amplas para o site, mas: R1) Como quiser! Existem infinitas formas de fazer isso R2) Você que sabe! é você que vai definir até que ponto o programa vai ser inteligente e quão preciso precisa ser o parsing. A maioria dos jogos desse tipo é bem simples e obriga o jogador a usar a estrutura "verbo complemento" mas só você define o limite do que seu código será capaz. R3) mais uma vez, depende do que você quer fazer; acho que você tem que definir casos de uso, frases que você gostaria que fossem aceitas e até onde quer investir nesse desenvolvimento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma simples de ler comandos e chamar a função correta, é usar o módulo `cmd` que vem com o python. Por exemplo:

```
comando> ajuda

Comandos disponíveis:
=====================
ajuda  andar  help  pegar  sair

comando> ajuda andar
Anda em uma das direções possíveis
comando> andar diagonal
Não há saída para este lado!
comando> andar norte
Você se desloca no sentido norte
comando> pegar faca
Voce pegou o item: faca
comando> pegar flor
flor não disponível no momento
```

Esse exemplo de execução foi feito com essa classe:

```
import cmd

class GameCommand(cmd.Cmd):
    prompt = "comando> "
    direcoes = ['norte', 'sul', 'leste', 'oeste', 'cima', 'baixo']
    doc_header = 'Comandos disponíveis:'

    def do_ajuda(self, comando):
        """Mostra ajuda"""
        return self.do_help(comando)

    def do_pegar(self, item):
        """Pega um item que esteja no local atual"""
        items = ['faca', 'disco', 'celular']
        if item in items:
            print('Voce pegou o item:', item)
        else:
            print(item, 'não disponível no momento')

    def do_andar(self, direcao):
        """Anda em uma das direções possíveis"""
        if direcao in self.direcoes:
            print('Você se desloca no sentido', direcao)
        else:
            print('Não há saída para este lado!')

    def do_sair(self, _ign):
        """Sai do jogo, lembre-se de salvar antes"""
        print('Saindo do jogo!!')
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = GameCommand()
    c.cmdloop()
```

Lembre-se que este é um exemplo simples, esta classe serviria apenas para você interpretar os comandos. Teria que criar classes para os elementos do jogo como você já está fazendo...

Esta forma de interpretação usa uma sintaxe mais simples "`comando argumentos`" então não usa regras gramaticais. Mas pode servir como um guia para como você vai despachar cada comando digitado para uma função específica que é executada.